# How do you get subscriber from observable in RXJava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

We are currently updating our Android app from RX1 to RX2. Some of the tests, however, rely on the Observer.onSubscribe() method, which no longer is supported in RX2. How can we get subscribers subscribed to an Observable in RX2? We can't find anything!

Here's a snippet. Pretty small, but all we're allowed to share:

```
private static class TestSubscribe<T> implements Observable.OnSubscribe<T> { 
    Set<Subscriber<? super T>> mSubscribers = new HashSet<>();
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
    mSubscribers.add(subscriber);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are refering to. Please provide one of those unit tests you try to convert to version 2.

Comment: Highly recommended reading before conversion: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0

Comment: @akarnokd Just posted the code above. We've read the link you provided (and just discovered WROTE!) before, but we're still facing issues the link doesn't provide answers to. Any help at all would be appreciated! – JStanger13 21 mins ago

Comment: Not sure why would you test that way, but you are looking for `ObservableSource` which has a `subscribe` method. You also need to use `io.reactivex.Observer<T>`